# Initial object of naturals in category theory

Tags: category-theory

How do I prove that Naturals numbers have a initial object in category theory? (It does not matter that it is 0 or 1 in both cases the sequence starts at a point and I want to prove that that point is a initial object).

There many examples given of initial objects, but no one on the web gave the naturals example, maybe because naturals do not have a initial object?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects

The requisite for something to be a initial object is the existence of a unique morphism from the initial object to every other object.

For naturals I have to prove that the morphisms from 0(1) to every other object is unique. It is possible to do that? If not, can I build a Naturals* category that have a initial object?

If I follow strictly Peano axioms (and I start from 0)

I have a unique morphism from 0 to 1

S:0->s(0):=1

A unique morphism from 0 to 2 which is a composition of S applied two times.

s(s(0))

But I'm not sure that counts as a proof.

Comment: You might need to be more precise with what your morphisms are. Are you saying that there's a morphism from $m$ to $n$ if $n = S(...S(m)...)$ for some number of applications of $S$? That seems to have uniqueness baked in. There isn't more than one way that that can be true.

Comment: Put another way, there isn't a unique category structure on a given set. You have to specify which one you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like we want the objects of our category to be the natural numbers and the morphisms to do with the successor functions $S_n: n \to n+1$. And since $S_n: n \to n+1$ and $S_{n+1}: n+1 \to n+2$ must be composable by the axioms of a category, any such composites must be morphisms too. These cannot compose to identities, so we must also include identities $1_n: n \to n$ for each natural number $n$. So I think we can define a category by essentially building off the subcategory of Set given by the natural numbers, their identities, and the relations $S_n: n \to n+1$ given by the peano axioms. It would have:

- For every natural number $n$, a morphism $1_n: n \to n$ which acts as an identity with respect to composition with successor functions.
- For every pair of natural numbers $m, n$, a morphism $m \to n$ iff there exists a composite $SSS\dots S$ such that $SSS\dots S(m)=n$. Note that this makes the arrow in each homset unique by definition, which also forces associativity (we have essentially interpreted the given set and functions as a poset).

Assuming the axiom of induction, for each nonzero natural number $n$, there is some composite of successor functions $SSS\dots S$ such that $SSS\dots S(0)=n$. This determines for each nonzero natural number $n$ a morphism $0 \to n$ which is unique by definition. The unique morphism $0 \to 0$ is the identity.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i was looking for. Really appreciate that